# retrieve randomly generated variable in a postman collection

Tags: postman

I created a collection that contains 2 requests:

The first query randomly generates an id each time it is executed in a Json object. Here's the response:

[image]

I have to get this id which is used in the 2nd request whose url has the following format:
my-test-environment/{{id}}

For this I created a variable in the collection by retrieving my id like this:

[image]

This works, but the problem is that if I replay the first query this id will be different and the second query will not return the expected status code.

How can I set this id correctly in my case ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add this to the `Tests` script of the first request:

```js
pm.collectionVariables.set('id', pm.response.json().id)
```

This will set a new `id` variable each time you hit send, this can be used in the next request.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help

Comment: Do you want to accept that as the answer?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot